# How to hide or remove sponsored products on amazon.de

Tags: amazon

How can I hide or remove all sponsored products in a amazon search result? For example if I sort the results by average customer review there are often much sponsored products in the list with no reviews at all with is very annoying for me.

In particular I am interested in `amazon.de` (where sponsored products in German are called "Gesponsert".

I didn't find any option in amazon to hide sponsored products and also tried the amazon lite addon for chromium, but it didn't work.

The best thing so far was the [amazon ad blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amazon-adblocker/hbiibabdaolgckcmmlkckjkcmmfdagap/related?authuser=1) for chromium. It works for amazon.com but not for the German version amazon.de.

Since I am not sure if such addons are save (or track what you do on amazon), maybe a solution using your OS hosts file would be great.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a solution using an OS host file is off-topic in Web Applications SE; that kind of solution is dependent on the operative system and should be asked on [su], [apple.se], [unix.se], [ubuntu.se] if they allow that kind of questions. Questions about a web browser extension recommendation might be asked on [softwarerecs.se]. The question might be reopened if more specific, i.e., about achieving the goal using a specific web browser and extension. There might be multiple questions, i.e. one for each different type of extension add blockers , userscripts

Answer (score 0):

Try Ad-Aware Adblocker and other products. They prevent you from being attacked personally and computer-wise; from serial attackers. I recommend Ad-Aware to all my friends/family. https://www.adaware.com